# Addition of phasors without a calculator

Tags: exponential-function

I am currently working through a class where phasors are introduced to add two sin waves. In the text it proposes the two phasors:

$$
    1\cdot e^{\frac{\pi}{3}j}
$$
    and
$$
    1\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}j}
$$

It then states that this is equal to:

$$
    \sqrt{3}\cdot e^{\frac{\pi}{2}j}
$$

I was able to confirm as much with a calculator however the class does not allow calculators on the test so I assume there is a easier way to add phasors. However I am unable to figure out how they got to the answer they did and I have looked through the text without being able to find where they state how to do it.

Comment: Expand Exp[j x] as Cos(x) + j Sin(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the euler formula $\exp(ix)=cos(x)+i sin(x)$ and combine the terms. You can use the arctan to get the argument but be careful which quadrant you are in.